# Работа с GET запросом и сохранение полученного файла

Tags: c#

Саму стуктуру запроса вроде понял. Данные приходят, но как их сохранить ни как не пойму.
Если уже обсуждалось - дайте ссылку где почитать.

Суто вопроса:
В ссылке передается текст TextSay.Text. В ответ Google отдает ссылку на mp3 файл с произношением этого текста.

```
             //Создаем объект для запроса к серверу
string s = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q=" + TextSay.Text + "&tl=ru";
HttpWebRequest r0 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(s);
r0.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "ru-ru,ru;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
r0.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.342.7 Safari/533.2";
r0.Method = "GET";
r0.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptCharset, "windows-1251,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");

               //возвращаем поток данных,
               //полученных от сервера
HttpWebResponse GoogleResponse = (HttpWebResponse)r0.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(GoogleResponse.GetResponseStream());
string GoogleSay= sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
```

Не могу разобраться, как сохранить этот фай на диск?

Если использовать этот метод:

```
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.DownloadFile(s, @"GoogleSay.mp3");
```

Всё срабатывает если текст на английском, если есть русские символы - ошибка (приходит ерунда, непонятного формата).

Нужно обрабатывать русские символы. Подскажите как лучше сделать? 
Еще вопрос: не могу подключить "System.Web.dll" к проекту. В списке ссылок, рядом с именем, восклицательный знак.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте сохранить файл так:

```
HttpWebRequest r = WebRequest.Create("http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q=text&tl=ru") as HttpWebRequest;
HttpWebResponse p = r.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
Stream s = p.GetResponseStream();
var fs = new FileStream("D:\\google.mp3", FileMode.Create);
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
while (s.CanRead)
{
    int byteread = s.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    fs.Write(buffer, 0, byteread);
}
```

З.Ы. Блок кода с использованием StreamReader лучше обернуть в using.